# Converting OpenXML to word with XLS

Tags: xslt

I have few paragraphs with the style "booktitle" I would like to convert those paragraphs to word table with the title "Book Title". The XML is below:

```
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="booktitle"/>…
</w:pPr>
<w:r>
<w:rPr/>
<w:t>First Paragraph</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="booktitle"/>…
</w:pPr>
<w:r>
<w:rPr/>
<w:t>second Paragraph</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:document>
```

Required Output:

Book Title
First Paragraph
Second Paragraph

My XSL is here:

```
<xsl:template match="w:p">
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test=".//w:pStyle[@w:val='booktitle']">
    <w:tbl>
      <w:tblPr>
        <w:tblBorders>
          <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="1" />
          <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="1" />
          <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="1" />
          <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="1" />
          <w:insideH w:val="single" w:sz="1" />
          <w:insideV w:val="single" w:sz="1" />
        </w:tblBorders>
      </w:tblPr>
      <w:tblGrid>
        <w:gridCol w:w="1024" />
        <w:gridCol w:w="1024" />
      </w:tblGrid>
      <w:tr><w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>Booktitle</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr>
      <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
          <w:tcPr>
            <w:tcW w:w="1024" />
          </w:tcPr>
    <w:p><w:r><w:t><xsl:value-of select=".//w:r/w:t"/></w:t></w:r></w:p>
        </w:tc>
      </w:tr>
      </w:tbl>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I am getting the output like

Booktitle
First Paragraph
Booktitle
Second Paragraph

The title is repeating for each node. Kindly help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take the table definition from the `w:p` template. You can also avoid the `xsl:choose` by using filters.

This is the main template, that defines the table start and end, and applies the `w:p` template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <w:tbl>
    <w:tblPr>
      <w:tblBorders>
        <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="1" />
        <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="1" />
        <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="1" />
        <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="1" />
        <w:insideH w:val="single" w:sz="1" />
        <w:insideV w:val="single" w:sz="1" />
      </w:tblBorders>
    </w:tblPr>
    <w:tblGrid>
      <w:gridCol w:w="1024" />
      <w:gridCol w:w="1024" />
    </w:tblGrid>
    <w:tr><w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>Booktitle</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//w:p[//w:pStyle/@w:val='booktitle']" />
    </w:tbl>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the `w:p` template which simply creates table rows:

```
<xsl:template match="w:p">
  <w:tr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="1024" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p><w:r><w:t><xsl:value-of select=".//w:r//w:t"/></w:t></w:r></w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your Quick reply. I am using OpcXsltTransform.exe for convertion, if i run with the above xsl i can't open the Word file it shows can't open the document there are some problems with content.

Comment: I hope because the w:p node defined in w:tr without <w:tbl>

Comment: I find the way to get it done by checking the first occurance. My stylesheet is below:`<xsl:template match="w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val='booktitle']"> <w:tbl><w:tr><w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t><xsl:value-of select=".//w:r/w:t"/></w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr></w:tbl></xsl:template>` `<xsl:template match="w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val='booktitle'][1]"><w:tbl><w:tr><w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>Booktitle</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr><w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t><xsl:value-of select=".//w:r/w:t"/></w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr></w:tbl></xsl:template>`